# SupportMultiDottedExtensions in WPF SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf

The WinForms `SaveFileDialog` has the `SupportMultiDottedExtensions` property which is very helpful when dealing with files that have multiple dots in them (e.g. file.app.xml).

The WPF `SaveFileDialog` has no such property and the behavior is that it only considers the last extension when appending extensions, filtering, etc.

Does anyone know how the "support multi-dotted extensions" behavior can be achieved in the WPF `SaveFileDialog`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use this in the Filter property.

eg. dialog.Filter = "App XML (.app.xml)|*.app.xml"

Comment: This will filter correctly (unlike the WinForms SaveFileDialog) but does not append suffixes correctly.  For example, entering "foo" into a SaveFileDialog will result in "foo.xml" being set in the `FileName` property.  After digging around this, I'm starting to think subclassing is the only way to get the WinForms behavior...